# The right way to load a CSS file in Rails 3.2 in production

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In our rails 3.2 app, a jquery-ui.css file was saved under app/assets/stylesheets/ for datepicker theme. In application view, the css file was referred as this:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
```

In applicaion.css.scss, did:

```
@import "jquery-ui.css";
```

In test environment, the CSS was referred correctly and there is theme with datepicker. However in production environment, there was none. We did assets precompile in production (with sub uri). Is there anything we missed in the setup?

### Update

config/environment/production.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some @import problems, regarding sass version https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/193.

Rename `"jquery-ui.css"` to `"_jquery-ui.scss"` and import it as partial `@import "jquery-ui";`

Use relative path from application.css.scss file `@import "relative/path/jquery-ui"`

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend stashing any 3rd party libraries in your vendor/assets library. For more info on this read through the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Move your jquery-ui.css to vendor/assets/stylesheets and try this instead of @import for you vendor manifest

```
/*
//= jquery-ui
*/
```

Comment: It is still not showing the css theme in production after the change.

Comment: How is the browser rendering your app.css.scss file in production? If your other styles in app.css.scss are rendering but that individual file is not, I would check to see how your caching is setup in production. If your sass rails gem is out of date it can also cause issues in your production environment.

Comment: scss file for simple_form under /assets/stylesheets/ is loaded properly. We used to load this jquery-ui.css from CDN. Considering the performance, we moved it to the server.

Comment: Can you show me what your config/environments/production.rb file looks like?